# After switching branches, Rails throws undefined method inside of a helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Not sure if I could reliably reproduce this, but sometimes when I switch branches in development all requests start throwing an undefined method error inside of a helper. The method is present on both branches. I am using global helpers (`helper :all`).

To fix the issue, I go into the helper file and save any change. Usually I just add a new line to the end of it. After saving, it works fine. Seems like a caching issue.

Has anyone else seen this and resolved it? I am on Rails 4.2.1. As far as I know this only happens in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Rails 4.2, `spring` has probably cached the code from the old branch.  After switching to the new branch remember to run:

```
spring stop
```

Spring will restart itself the next time you run the server, tests, or other Rails commands.

Comment: Running with DISABLE_SPRING=1 does not fix the issue.